# Is Kingston KVR800D2N6/2G compatible with KVR800D2N5/1G

Tags: memory, compatibility

I have 2 bars of `KVR800D2N6/2G` and 2 bars of `KVR800D2N5/1G` and want to insert them into `ASUS P5Q-EM` which supports up to 16 GB of such memory.

The main problem is - first two are `N6` and second two are `N5`. Are they compatible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are compatible. N6 modules just have slower timings. Installed together faster modules will work with slower timings.